# Short circuit instance with a switching regulator

Tags: inductor, short-circuit, switching-regulator, full-bridge

I am currently working on a receiver circuit for a wireless power transfer system. I made a basic full bridge rectifier with schottky diodes before.I thought of changing the diodes to a FBR IC and added a switching regulator ([LT1377](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/13727fbs.pdf)) after the [Full bridge rectifier](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/345/db101s-1012s-17410.pdf) (FBR) output so as to get a stable output voltage.

[image]

I soldered the components to the PCB and started testing, I noticed that the circuit was causing a short circuit. I removed the FBR ic and connected the power supply directly to the output of the FBR. And started testing again, after a few test i noticed that the inductor is causing a short circuit. After reaching about 4V,0.2A on the power supply the current shoots up to 2A.i have already changed burnt through a Switching regulator. I am not sure exactly what is wrong with the circuit as i have wired it up similar to what is given in the datasheet.

[image]

The input parameters to which I am designing it to is ~22V, 0.2-0.3A and want a stable voltage output of 20V,0.2-0.3A. I have not been able to test past 5V since the circuit becomes short circuit and risks burning the switching regulator.

My first impression was the FBR was not suitable because i have connected its (-) to the ground plane and is connected to the same ground as the other components, but i have removed it now and testing it with the power supply directly connected to the outputs of the said FBR, but till getting the same issue. I have tested the circuit also with shottky diodes inplace of using the FBR and still get the same issue of the short circuit.

Comment: You have a boost converter, so the output voltage has to be larger than the input voltage.  What's the breakdown voltage of the TVS you have on the output?

Comment: @JohnD, Thank you for pointing that out, I know that the regulator can be used as a Buck converter, but I guess I connected the inputs to the feedback wrong? Would I have to connect the Feedback to the NFB? i was confused about this at the time of designing the circuit as it said negative output voltage setting given on pg7 of the datasheet.

Comment: Well you could make a SEPIC or a flyback with this part, but it's not intended to be used as a simple buck converter, and your schematic will not work as a buck converter either, no matter how you connect the feedback.

Comment: @JohnD So there is no chance to use the above switching regulator as a buck converter?

Comment: @JohnD, even if this was not possible, do you have any idea as to why there is a short circuit/ large current draw from the power supply, like I mentioned above, after about 4-5V on the input, the Power supply current shoots up to 2A.

Comment: The switch current limit is well above the saturation limit of your inductor, so during startup your inductor is probably saturating.  If the switch turns on into a saturated inductor, the current limit might not be fast enough to save it.

Comment: @JohnD Would a larger inductor with a higher current saturation range mitigate this issue?

Comment: Yes, a larger inductor should mitigate the issue.  (But still won't make it a buck converter.)

Comment: @JohnD As you pointed out, the IC was the issue, I went with a L5973 switching regulator, and it works perfectly now.